# Convert VB function to Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net

Any VB/Javascript guru out there that can convert this for me?

```
Protected Function RelativeTime(ByVal dtTime As DateTime) As String
        Dim timeDiff As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(dtTime)

        If timeDiff.TotalMinutes < 1 Then
            Return "less than a minute ago."
        ElseIf timeDiff.TotalMinutes < 2 Then
            Return "about one minute ago"
        ElseIf timeDiff.TotalMinutes < 60 Then
            Return String.Format("about {0:N0} minutes ago", timeDiff.TotalMinutes)
        ElseIf timeDiff.TotalHours < 2 Then
            Return "about an hour ago"
        ElseIf timeDiff.TotalHours < 12 Then
            Return String.Format("about {0:N0} hours ago", timeDiff.TotalHours)
        ElseIf timeDiff.TotalDays < 365 Then
            Return dtTime.ToString("MMM d")
        Else
            Return dtTime.ToString("MMM d, yyyy")
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: What day do we get paid, and where can we meet up to split your paycheck?

Comment: Not a nice way to ask for help.

Comment: This isn't a site where people do the work for you; we try to answer questions and point you in the right direction so that you can do it yourself.

Comment: @mokumax: If you look at [that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266348/convert-javascript-function-to-c) carefully, you will see that the two answers provided didn't actually perform a direct conversion of the code. Rather, they suggested a better technique. StackOverflow isn't really designed to be a clearing-house for translating other people's code.

Comment: This post should be deleted as it provides no useful information for anyone looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of answers on SO that address this. Just search for "[javascript time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+time+ago)".

Comment: Perfect.  Simple and to the point.